# XSLT: Adding a processing instruction at the end of the file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a `<?hard-pagebreak?>` PI at the end of a whole bunch of .xml files (ie. on a new line after the last node?  Whats the best way for a XSLT to do that?

Example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section version="5"
         xml:id="summary"
         xreflabel="Issues Summary"
         xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
...stuff
</section>
<!-- need page break here -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <RootNode> 
  </RootNode>
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="hard-pagebreak" />
</xsl:template>
```

**update** 
The below is an improved version of above that also copies the source XML document

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="hard-pagebreak" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nope :( that killed my contents of the xml file.  I'll update my question to what my sample .xml looks like

Comment: The <RootNode></RootNode> part is only a placeholder for your own xsl code. You should simply add an <xsl:processing-instruction> after closing the last tag in your output, as seen in this answer.

Comment: There is no attributes of the document root

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this: http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_processing-instruction.asp